# Sequence of inserts and slow delete

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert, sql-delete

I'm sending data from one table to another. and then I'm deleting it from the source table.

The problem is that sometimes it gets very slow even when I do a few records.

Some of my tables have more than 6 million records, but I am running the script to send a few records, 100 thousand at the most, and I would run the script several times until I managed to transfer all the records, since if I was going to do with everyone I need would take days.

Example of my script

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
--INSERTS
INSERT INTO NewTable1([Id],[Date],[Col3]) 
SELECT [Id],[Date],[Col3] 
from Table1 tn 
WHERE  tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
INSERT INTO NewTable2([Col1],[table1_id],[Col3],[Col4]) 
SELECT [Col1],[table1_id],[Col3],[Col4] 
from Table2 t1 
inner join Table1 tn 
    on t1.id = tn.table1_id 
WHERE tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
...
    
INSERT INTO NewTable100([Col1],[table1_id]) 
SELECT [Col1],[table1_id] 
from Table100 t1 
inner join Table1 tn 
   on t1.id = tn.table1_id 
WHERE  tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
--DELETES
    
DELETE t 
FROM Table100 t 
INNER JOIN Table1 tn 
   On t.table1_id = tn.id  
WHERE  tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
...
    
DELETE t 
FROM Table2 t 
INNER JOIN Table1 tn 
    On t.table1_id = tn.id  
WHERE  tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
DELETE tn 
FROM Table1 tn 
WHERE  tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';
    
COMMIT;
```

some way to improve this script

Comment: Is that server still taking transactions elsewhere or only your process is running?

Comment: other transactions are carried out, we cannot stop the system to run this script

Comment: Ok, based on the script example, if the commit comes only after you do all Inserts or/and Deletes, you are still doing in the same batch. So, do commits more frequently to avoid that. You could implement a loop that would make inserts and deletes based on the date and then commit after each iteration.

Comment: I put the commit at the end, because in case of an error in some insert or delete, I need to do the rollback.

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease the number of reads form tables by loading the data you want into a temp table first and work with temp table, for example :

```
SELECT [Col1],[table1_id],[Col3],[Col4] , [Id],[Date]
INTO #LoadedDate1
from Table2 t1 
inner join Table1 tn 
    on t1.id = tn.table1_id 
    and tn.[Date] >= '2017-11-01 01:00' 
    and tn.[Date] <= '2017-11-02 01:00';

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

--INSERTS

INSERT INTO NewTable1([Id],[Date],[Col3]) 
SELECT [Id],[Date],[Col3] 
from #LoadedDate1
    
INSERT INTO NewTable2([Col1],[table1_id],[Col3],[Col4]) 
SELECT [Col1],[table1_id],[Col3],[Col4] 
from #LoadedDate1
    
--DELETES   
    
DELETE t 
FROM Table2 t 
INNER JOIN #LoadedDate tn 
    On t.table1_id = tn.id  

DELETE tn 
FROM Table1 tn 
INNER JOIN #LoadedDate tn 
    On t.table1_id = tn.id  

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this.

```
declare @startDate datetime = '2017-11-01 01:00'
declare @endDate datetime = '2017-11-02 01:00'

while (select top 1 from  Table1 where date between @startDate and  @endDate) is not null
begin

begin transaction
    INSERT INTO NewTable1([Id],[Date],[Col3]) 
    SELECT [Id],[Date],[Col3] 
    from Table1 tn 
    WHERE  tn.[Date] between @startDate and  @endDate


    DELETE t 
    FROM Table1 t 
    WHERE  tn.[Date] between @startDate and  @endDate

commit
   
   set  @startDate =  DATEADD(day, 1,  @startDate)
   set  @endDate =  DATEADD(day, 1,  @endDate)


end
```

I am doing it by day but you could divide that by hour minutes, months or whatever way is better for you.